# NightwatchJS how to emit html5 drag drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, nightwatch.js

Maybe someone knows how to drag elements which have implemented html5 drag&drop.
I need this in e2e test using nightwatchjs.
I tried:

```
        browser.useCss()
        .moveToElement("div.test-dragbtn-row",10,10)
        .mouseButtonDown(0)
        .moveToElement('div.test-container-root',50,50)
        .mouseButtonUp(0).pause(3000);
```

In browser I can see that element is pressed, but second move not works, moreover it holds mouse down on element until I enter physically with mouse into browser window.

Maybe someone done test with nightwatchjs for drag and drop, and knows how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom command and it is working in chrome and firefox

dragAndDrop.js:

```
module.exports.command = function(source, dest, callback) {
  var self = this;

  this.moveToElement(source,  10,  10)
  .mouseButtonDown(0)
  .pause(500)
  .moveToElement(dest,  10,  10)
  .mouseButtonUp(0);

  return this;
};
```

Comment: What happen when element has smaller size than 10px (2nd and 3rd argument) ? I think (source,0,0) and (dest,0,0) will be safer.

Comment: I Agree with you is just an example :)

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue resolved by using this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd

It simulates a drag and drop by dispatching dnd events, no mouse involved. It is not ideal, as you may be relying on mouse events to make other stuff happen, but it did the trick for me.